# Node testing.test is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Im trying to call a function in another file but no matter what I do, it will not recognize that function. I get

> uncaughtException: testing.test is not a function

```
//testing.js
module.exports = function(){
    return{
        "test" : function(){
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            console.log('worked!')
                resolve(resolve({'data': "success"}))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And then in any other file:

```
//other file
var testing = require("testing.js");
testing.test().then(function(data){
   console.log(data) 
})
```

I know the directory is correct, my IDE even shows that what I'm trying to call is a function. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `testing` is a function (that's what you are exporting).  You have to call it in order to get the object you want.

```
//other file
var testing = require("testing.js");
testing().test().then(function(data){    // added parens after testing()
   console.log(data) 
})
```

Or, change the export to just export the object directly so you don't have to call a function first to get the object:

```
//testing.js
module.exports = {
    "test" : function(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        console.log('worked!')
            resolve(resolve({'data': "success"}))
        })
    }
}

// then, this will work because testing is the actual object
var testing = require("testing.js");
testing.test().then(function(data){
   console.log(data) 
})
```

Choose one or the other of these two options.  Keeping the `export` as a function allows you to fetch a new object (like calling a constructor or factory function), each time you call the function.  Exporting the object directly allows all users or your module to have access to the same object.  So, which way to go ultimately depends upon what type of design you want.  You just have to make sure the caller and the callee are acting in concert to use the exported value appropriately.

Comment: The wizards have spoken. Thanks :) Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Change `testing.js` to the following:

```
module.exports = {
    "test" : function() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            console.log('worked!')
            resolve(resolve({'data': "success"}))
        })
    }
}
```

Now a object with a property called `test` is being exported, so you can use it in the way you intended in the other file:

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: Now a object with a property called `test` is being exported, so you can use it in the way you intended in the other file

Comment: Please put that explanation in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This makes sense. The codebase I was working with is quite complex in how it chooses to do things.